# Which sentence is correct? with "it" or without "it"

Tags: sentence-structure, clauses

> The afterlife is a life that some people believe **it** begins when a
> person dies.
>
> The afterlife is a life that some people believe begins when a person
> dies.

Which one is correct? The correct sentence is from a book. But I am a little confused about the sentence structure and clauses. Please help me analyze it.

Comment: You arent wrong, this is confusing!

Comment: Without *it* is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The afterlife is a life that some people believe begins when a person dies.

This is correct ^

You cannot include "it" as it is already referenced to using "that" in "that some people believe". Adding a "it" results in "that some people believe it", which is grammatically wrong.

Think of it like this

> The afterlife is a life | that some people believe | begins when a person dies

Add in a "it"

> The afterlife is a life | that some people believe | it begins when a person dies

Which references to "the afterlife is a life that begins when a person dies", twice, which disrupts the flow of the sentence.